# DLL written in Delphi 10 is giving Access Violation when called from Delphi 6

Tags: delphi

I have written a small DLL in Delphi 10.2 to make use of the FTPS functionality that the Indy components have.
Calling the DLL from a test app, also written in Delphi 10, works 100%. However, calling the DLL from a Delphi 6 app gives me an access violation in borlndmm.dll. Here is a simple example of code to connect to the FTP server.

```
{The function in my object:}
function TQXFTP.Connect: Boolean;
begin
    Result := False;

    IdFTP.Host     := fHost;
    IdFTP.Username := fUserName;
    IdFTP.Password := fPassword;

    try
        IdFTP.Connect;

        if IdFTP.Connected then
        begin
            Result := True;
        end;
    except
        on E:Exception do
        begin
            fErrorOccurred := True;
            fErrorMessage := E.Message;
        end;
    end;
end;

{Code from my DLL}
function FTPConnect(Host: string;
                    UserName: string;
                    PassWord: string): string; stdcall;
var
    QXFTP: TQXFTP;
begin
    Result := '';
    QXFTP  := TQXFTP.Create;
    try
        QXFTP.Host                 := Host;
        QXFTP.UserName             := UserName;
        QXFTP.PassWord             := PassWord;

        if QXFTP.Connect then
            QXFTP.Disconnect;

        if QXFTP.ErrorOccurred then
            Result := QXFTP.ErrorMessage
        else
            Result := '';

    finally
        FreeAndNil(QXFTP);
    end;    
end;

exports
    FTPConnect;

{Code from my D6/D10 Test App}
function FTPConnect(Host: string;
                    UserName: string;
                    PassWord: string): string; stdcall;  external QXFTPDLL.dll';


procedure TfrmFTP.btnFTPConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    lsFTPResult: string;
begin
    lsFTPResult := FTPConnect(edtHost.Text,
                              edtUserName.Text,
                              edtPassword.Text);
    if lsFTPResult = '' then
        ShowMessage('FTP was sucessfull')
    else
        ShowMessage('FTP Failed: - ' + lsFTPResult);

end;
```

Comment: Are you aware about Unicode strings by default in D10.2 and ANSI ones in D6? Moreover, string retrieving might be a problem due to memory managing issues.

Comment: My guess would be it is differences in string handling. String can be problematic with DLLs anyway, so I would suggest that you try without using strings (e.g. a word for the error code and try zero/non zero) to confirm this, then take it from there. If that works then maybe use AnsiString or similar, but as I say, strings can be problematic anyway.

Comment: Please, do yourself a favour and read [my article about writing DLLs](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html). The tips given there even apply to DLLs to be used by different versions of Delphi. The main problem here seems to be the difference in string types. Don't pass Delphi strings (or any other Delphi-and-version-specific types) across DLL borders. The article describes how to handle strings properly.

Comment: Not to mention, even the result shouldn't be of any string type. Function results across DLL boundaries should only return simple types, such as `Integer`.

Comment: @Jerry: see my article. <g>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace String type with WideString in exported function declaration. This is the only way, because strings have completely different format and memory layout in Delphi 10.2 and Delphi 6. On the other hand, WideString is just a wraper around Microsoft's BSTR, and is the same in all versions of Delphi.

Comment: `WideString` is not the ONLY way. You could use a plain `PWideChar` instead.

Comment: Technically yes, but it will require some additional work to release memory.

Comment: only when the DLL has to return strings to the app. For input-only parameters, the app controls both allocation and deallocation, it is just passing in a pointer. In fact that is still the case even with `WideString` input parameters. The app just uses the COM memory manager for both allocation and deallocation, which is less efficient than using the RTL's memory manager

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much for everybody's input. I first changed all my strings to PChar. This removed the access violation but I still could not connect to my FTP host. I knew it must've been a string conversion error since hard coding the host, user and pwd in the DLL allowed me to connect even if I call the DLL from my Delphi 6 app. I then changed all the PChar variables & parameters to WideString (as suggested above) and that seems to have solved to problem. I can now connect and copy the files to my FTP server successfully.

Comment: `PChar` is `PAnsiChar` in Delphi 6, but is `PWideChar` in Delphi 10.2

Answer (score -3):

The cause for your problem is that you have designed your DLL in a way that it is using memory sharing with the main application. And in order to do so both DLL and main aplication must be using same memory mannager.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Sharing_Memory

Now Delphi 10 is using FastMM memory manager, but if my memory serves me corectly Delphi 6 is still using old Borland Memory manager. This is then causing incompatibility between DLL memory manager and the one used in your main application.

You might sovle this problem by replacing the old Borland Memory Manager with FastMM memory manager which is open source and can be retrived from here https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM4

Comment: The issue is not just about the memory manager. The `string` type itself is different between Delphi 6 and 10.2 and has a completely different memory layout in the two versions. `string` has never been an interop-safe type to use across DLL boundaries.

Comment: @SilverWarrior: As Remy says, the string types are different. And it is never a good idea to pass Delphi strings to and from DLLs. OP should read [my article](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html#allocations) and do what is described there.